# Rounded Corner Progressbar on App Widgets

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I am creating a widget for my app. Currently I am just using a normal Horizontal ProgressBar. It works just fine. But I was finding a way to make the corners of the progress bar round. As the remoteviews are limited to specific things, I cannot use a custom progressbar. So can anyone point me a way to make the progressbars round on my appwidget. Really Appreciate it.

I did try to use a RelativeLayout as a progressbar by changing its width on runtime. But changing width on runtime was only possible for API 31+

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [LinearProgressIndicator](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/progressindicator/LinearProgressIndicator) :

[image]

```
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:trackColor="@color/black"
        app:trackCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:trackThickness="12dp" />
```

Comment: LinearProgressIndicator is not supported in RemoteViews

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read your question clearly, I've just done some research about the `remoteviews`, did you try to achieve your needs by playing with `drawable` ?